# inseting xml data to mysql database via php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to read an xml file using `file_get_contents()` and then insert this file to my mysql database but i have an error on my code, please see my code below:

```
//details ommited
$address= $_GET['address'];
$xml = file_get_contents($address);
db_connect(); // my db connection function
$query = "INSERT INTO feeds SET name = '$name' , xml_data = '$xml' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{
   echo mysql_error();
}
// end of my code
```

So , when i add `, xml = '$xml'` to my sql `$query`, php show this error to me:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's OFF-state current.]]></description>\n\t\t\t</' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions

- use PDO parameter binding
- escape your xml input

With how you're currently doing it, $xml may have a character that is ending your sql statement prematurly.  I have no idea what character could cause this, but my suggestions should fix that.

Comment: can you explain a bit more ,please?

Comment: if i use escape characters, after i fetch this xml from my db , won't have any problems with parsing my xml?

Comment: That's an excellent point. I didn't think of that. You'll need to do parameter binding at a minimum to prevent SQL injection. I'm not sure if escaping input is necessary or the extent that parameter binding will do that. You might have to unescape your xml after fetching from the db. I don't know for sure, so I'll have to leave that as an exercise for you.